# AWS S3 upload speeds very slow

Tags: amazon-s3

I have a 20 Mbps symmetrical pipe. Upload speed to AWS S3 tops out at 2.3 Mbps. Tried the multipart upload but even with 10 concurrent threads, the total speed remains the same, just gets split between all threads ~20 KB/s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you verify that the metric you are looking at is 2.3 Mbps vs 2.3 MB/s? 2.3 MB/s is pretty close to 20 Mbps. [This AWS blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2016/04/transfer-files-into-amazon-s3-up-to-300-percent-faster/) explains how to upload faster and some tools to verify the upload connection as well.

Comment: Could you summarise the gist of the content you link to? Maybe also worth mentioning that your comment does suggest the OP may not be able to gain any benefits from the service you link to, since 2.3MB/s is pretty close to maxing out the OP's uplink.

Comment: Oops, good point. I was indeed confusing MBps with Mbps. I'm maxed out on my pipe, not AWS. Make much more sense now.